# Freezer not cooling

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Samsung RF266 bottom-freezer refrigerator from 2010.  The fridge part is working fine; the freezer part is suddenly not able to cool below ~35°F.

I took off the evaporator cover and there was noticeable frost buildup on one of the pipes leading into or out of the evaporator:

[image: picture of frost buildup on pipe next to evaporator coils]

Any ideas on what might cause this?  Is this a situation to try to repair or is it time to get a new fridge?

Comment: Is there a fan in there that has stopped working. One refrigerator that I had for over 20 years had to have the fan replaced twice in its lifetime.

Comment: I was able to confirm the fan was working by listening with the freezer door slightly cracked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my reading, the real sign of a problem here is not the frost buildup on the one pipe... but the fact there there is no frost anywhere else.

Consider this (from [mastersamuraitech.com](https://mastersamuraitech.com/module-2/evaporator-frost-pattern-analysis/evaporator-frost-pattern-analysis-2/)):

[image: evaporator frost pattern analysis]

Similarly this (from [fixitnow.com](https://fixitnow.com/wp/2011/02/25/how-to-troubleshoot-warm-refrigerator-problems-by-reading-the-evaporator-frost-pattern/)):

[image: evaporator frost showing likely refrigerant leak]

See also a discussion of a similar problem at [appliantology.org](https://appliantology.org/topic/59894-samsung-rsg257aars/).

It seems that this is very likely a refrigerant leak.  As such it's probably not a DIY fix (certainly not for me) and it's probably more cost-effective to buy a new fridge.

Answer (score 0):

As a licensed hvac person that mostly repairs very large units compared to this I have repaired a few fridges for myself and firends by adding the correct type of Freon. In most cases I have seen a fridge of this case will take r134 or r404, both are inexpensive but most inexpensive or downright cheap units don't have a port to add the Freon, for less than 10$ a clamp on port can be added, for about 75$  the system can be pumped down and a Schrader port added,,then the air pumped out again and the system refilled and topped off. I have had better luck with the Schrader port than the clamp on 2 of these have failed and after installing a Schrader port both worked, with cheap or small units the clamp on port is worth the chance.  With a high end fridge I would go with the soldered a shreader nipple, it won't leak or less than clamp on and is just as easy to top off:  not sure what happened to the rest of my answer but a low charge will cause icing. Most of the time it is not worth the cost unless you or a friend has the gear & license and not many help out now.

Comment: Interesting.  I've had a few develop tiny leaks and have been told that it wasn't practical to fix them.  I don't imagine you can fix a leak by changing refrigerant.  Are you describing another potential cause of the OP's problem?  How would the wrong refrigerant get in a consumer refrigerator in the first place (I could see an incompetent tech screwing up when servicing a commercial unit)?